# AJAX or Javascript POST request for Django form and get the result

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, post, django-forms

I am working on a django based project in which I have integrated ML trained models to check if a https url is legitimate or not. for this I need javascript or ajax to call a rest api for my form in which I want to send a post request so that I can check if a https url is legitimate or not.

**NOTE: My code is running successfully and giving correct answers on postman. so just want to integrate it with my HTML form**

form.html:

```
<form role="form" class="form" onsubmit="return false;">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="data">SITE URL</label>
        <textarea id="data" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button id="post" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">POST</button>
    </form>

    <div id="output" class="container"></div>

    <script src="/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function () {
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        document.getElementById('post').onclick = function () {
          var data = document.getElementById('data').value;

          axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict/', JSON.parse(data))
            .then(function (res) {
              output.className = 'container';
              output.innerHTML = res.data;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              output.className = 'container text-danger';
              output.innerHTML = err.message;
            });
        };
      })();
    </script>
```

urls.py:

```
path('form/', form, name="form"),
path('predict/', predict, name='predict')
```

here `predict/` URL is for my ML model to validate a https URL
ML Model:
I am returning this response:

```
if list(model.predict([test]))[0] == 1:
        return JsonResponse({"Response":"Legitimate"})
else:
    return JsonResponse({"Response":"Phishing or fake"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Below I have provided an example, since you are just looking for a possible solution:

```
<form role="form" action="{% url 'predict' %}" class="form" 
    onsubmit="newPrediction(event, this)">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="data">SITE URL</label>
        <textarea id="data" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button id="post" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">POST</button>
</form>
    
<script>
function newPrediction(e, form) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const output = document.getElementById('output');
        const formData = new FormData(form);
    
        fetch(form.action, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(html => {
            output.innerHTML = html.Response
        });
      }
</script>
```

Please comment if you have further questions and I will update this answer.

Comment: okay let me check it. I am just pasting it because I am not familiar with js much

Comment: I have checked it but still not working.

Comment: it even didn't submitted the data